Bitmask permissions
It's a tutorial problem in a Linux course:
The command ls -la / gives this result:
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4096 Apr 15 23:39 .
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4096 Apr 15 23:39 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Jan 28 22:23 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Jan 28 22:30 boot
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root  3320 Apr 15 23:24 dev
drwxr-xr-x  73 root root  4096 Apr 15 23:24 etc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Feb  5 20:55 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Jan 28 22:23 lib -> usr/lib
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Jan 28 22:23 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jan 28 22:23 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 28 22:23 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 28 22:23 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 133 root root     0 Apr 15 23:24 proc
drwx------   5 root root  4096 Apr 15 23:47 root
drwxr-xr-x  17 root root   520 Apr 15 23:25 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 Jan 28 22:23 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxrwxrwx   3 root root  4096 Apr 15 23:40 something
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 28 22:23 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Apr 15 23:24 sys
drwxrwxrwt   8 root root  4096 Apr 15 23:47 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Jan 28 22:23 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Jan 28 22:23 var

The command sudo ls -lR /something produces this result:
/something:
total 4
drw-r-xr-x 3 george george 4096 Apr 16 14:24 one

/something/one:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 george george 4096 Apr 15 23:47 two

/something/one/two:
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 george george 7 Apr 15 23:47 somefile

We work under the user george, i.e. the command whoami gives us george. The groups george command gives us the result george : george users.
What result do we get for the cat /something/one/two/somefile command and why?
My attempt to solve the problem:
1. Let's see what access rights we have to somefile:
The file somefile has -rwxrwxrwx rights, hence the users user, group and other have all the rights to read, write and execute this file.Hence, the user george can read this file.
2. Let's make sure that somefile exists:
Running the sudo ls -lR /something command displays a list of all files and subdirectories in the /something directory, including permissions information and file size, with superuser privileges. The file is located in the /something/one/two/somefile directory.
3. Let's check the access rights of the directory /something/one/two/somefile :
Directory one has access rights drw-r-xr-x - user george has permission to enter this directory, and read the contents;
Directory two has drwxr-xr-x access rights - user george has permission to enter this directory, and to read the contents;
By executing the cat /something/one/two/somefile command we will be able to view the contents of the somefile.
The ls -l command shows that the ```somefile`` file weighs 7 bytes. If the file contains text or characters, they will be displayed in the console.
My mentor says these hypotheses need to be tested.
How do I test this task?

how would you test By executing the cat /something/one/two/somefile command we will be able to view the contents of the somefile.?

Thr prrmissions, and mount options, along the path from / to your target matter. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

"user george has permission to enter this directory, and read the contents;" -- does he? Why or why not?
